# Export and overwrite pages on import?

Tags: migration

I'm doing a major rework of an existing homepage in my dev environment. There are some new pages but also lots of changes to existing pages. How can I best transfer these changes to my live environment? Exporting and importing only works for pages that does not already exists, it seems.

I would like to export chosen content and overwrite existing content if it exists. I'm not in a position to just migrate the entire site since the live site is an active site with lot's of daily updates on some parts.

Answer (score 1):

You have a narrow selection to choose from. Either replace the database [tables](https://wp-cli.org/commands/db/tables/) with something like [wp-cli](https://wp-cli.org/commands/db/) or have a special import-export process for your data.

If you want to make this granular, you could make a [post metabox](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) to import/export post content and metadata as json. Then updates could be incremental and on the fly.

But if you develop locally on a different database, then you run the risk of your post IDs being out of sync. So keep that in mind during import/export in any way you choose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do have wp-cli installed but I never meddled with the database before so it's new territory for me. Does the database table for a page contain everything associated with it? Like images, ACF-fields etc?

Comment: act is probably in the post meta fields, so that's one table. Images will be stored as references so you'll have to physically move them and change the references. But that is what http://wp-cli.org/commands/search-replace/ is for.